# Receiving error while running Android tests via selenium grid

Tags: selenium, appium, selenium-grid, appium-android

When I try to execute my android test directly through appium it works fine. But when I try to execute it through selenium grid it is giving me this error in the hub.

```
org.openqa.grid.common.exception.CapabilityNotPresentOnTheGridException: cannot find : Capabilities {app: /Users/prakashp/IdeaProject..., appPackage: com.ytlcomms.ymca, appiumVersion: 1.7.2, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: UiAutomator2, avd: Pixel_2_API_22, browserName: android, clearSystemFiles: true, deviceName: Pixel_2_API_22, fullReset: false, noReset: false, platform: ANDROID, platformName: android, version: 5.1}
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.ProxySet.verifyAbilityToHandleDesiredCapabilities(ProxySet.java:153)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry.addNewSessionRequest(DefaultGridRegistry.java:217)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:111)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:86)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Below is the hubConfig:

```
{
  "host": "10.24.4.179",
  "port": 4654,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,

  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "maxSession": 5,
  "jettyMaxThreads":-1
}
```

Below is the nodeconfig (Not sure whether it's correct)

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "platformname": "Android",
      "platformVersion": "5.1.1",
      "deviceName": "Pixel_2_API_22",
      "app": "/Users/prakashp/IdeaProjects/ymca/src/test/resources/YMCA.apk",
      "newCommandTimeout": 60,
      "browserName": "android"
    }
  ],

  "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
  "timeout": 30000,
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "url": "http://10.24.4.179:4501/wd/hub",
  "host": "10.24.4.179",
  "port": "4501",
  "maxSession": 1,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hubPort": "4654",
  "hubHost": "10.24.4.179"
}
```

Then in the code I have set the following capabilities:

```
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel_2_API_22");
    dcap.setCapability("avd", "Pixel_2_API_22");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.7.2");
    dcap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxxxxx.xxxx");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES, "true");
    dcap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, "false");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, "false");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1");
    dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/prakashp/IdeaProjects/xxxx/src/test/resources/YMCA.apk");
```

Kindly help as I am new to mobile automation.

Comment: Not that it would solve your problem, but wouldn't the browser name be "chrome" instead of "android?"

Comment: @BillHileman I changed, but it didn't help. I am very badly stuck at this.